# Cortana Skill - Start Cortana by trigger

Tags: azure, bots, botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I wan't my cortana skill to ask the user something after a specific interval.

If I am testing this code with the bot emulator it works (the bot responds responds to me after the interval is over).

But if I deploy the bot, cortana isn't starting up after the interval:

- I talk to cortana
- I close the window
- I wait for the interval
- Nothing happens (cortana
  doesn't shows up automatically after the interval is over).

Where is the mistake?
(I used the simpleSendMessage from here but added one line: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages)

In the ConversationStarter, the .Speak line is new:

```
        message.From = botAccount;
        message.Recipient = userAccount;
        message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId);
        message.Text = "Hello, this is a notification";
        message.Speak = "Hello, this is a notification";
        message.Locale = "en-Us";
        await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```

Edit: It seems in any way it can be possible. But how? Or is this functionality only able for native cortana?

[image]

Comment: the Cortana channel does not currently support proactive messages

Comment: Thanks. Sadly I might have known it :(

Answer (score 0):

As Jason mentioned, the Cortana channel does not currently support proactive messages. It's a highly requested feature and also a part of our backlog - although I don't have any specific timeline to share.